# Assigning log to variable

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

Using the logging module I want to assign the log to a variable but this is not a lib I am confident with and I can't find what I'm looking for in the documentation as I don't know exactly what to search for.

This doesn't work:

```
data = logger.info(ws.get_data("test"))
```

Comment: Could you let us know what you hope to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth taking a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) to see how logs are processed. Inspecting the source code shows that `logger.info` does not return anything. The example above is akin to `a = print('this')`. It does call `logger._log` which ultimately calls `logger.makeRecord`. There's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects) on how to directly produce a record but it's not user friendly because it's not typically useful.